# Thanks be to you, John

Tags: grammaticality

Is "Thanks, John." a short form for "Thanks be to you, John."? Is "Thanks, John." a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The [etymology of the word](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thanks&searchmode=none) shows that it originated as a shortened form of "I give you thanks":

> As short for *I give you thanks* from 1580s; often with extensions, e.g. *thanks a lot* (1908). Spelling *thanx* attested by 1907.

This is similar to many other constructions in English:

> Hello, John.
>
> Greetings, John.
>
> Goodbye, John.

The most relevant extended form would be:

> I give you thanks, John.

Answer (score 0):

While "Thanks be to you, John" is a grammatically correct sentence, for me it doesn't sound so natural. It's too stilted. The only time I'd use that construction is when I'm hearing Mass and say: Thanks be to God!

Stick to "Thanks, John", and--yes--it's a grammatically correct sentence, too!

Comment: But it doesn't have a verb.

Comment: @JohnLee And where did you get the idea that all sentences must have verbs? Think about these sentences: a. Yes, John. b. Good morning, John. Where are the verbs in these complete sentences?

Comment: It has the implied subject and verb "*I give* (my) thanks (to you), John.

Comment: Speaking of the sentence *Yes, John,* there is a hidden verb.  It is a contraction of Old English *ge si!* 'so be it!'